# One out of ten partials suddenly becomes slow (random)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

When I look at my log-file, I get the following lines:

```
...
Rendered partials/_something.html.erb (11.8ms)
Rendered partials/_something.html.erb (123.8ms)
Rendered partials/_something.html.erb (8.2ms)
Rendered partials/_something.html.erb (7.3ms)
Rendered partials/_something.html.erb (7.1ms)
Rendered partials/_something.html.erb (8.5ms)
Rendered partials/_something.html.erb (7.2ms)
Rendered partials/_something.html.erb (7.1ms)
Rendered partials/_something.html.erb (7.4ms)
Rendered partials/_something.html.erb (7.9ms)
...
```

I include them the following way

```
@collection.each do |something|
    render :partial => 'partials/something', :locals => {:something => something}
end
```

I find it pretty weird that the second render (of the same partial) in this case takes much longer than any other render. However, when I reload the page, some other render is taking much more time, while the `@collection`-variable is still in the same order.

I actually don't really know how to profile this. I mean, when it's the same `something` that causes a slow response I'ld be able to figure it out. But it seams to be just a random one. Could this be some memory leak or so?

I hope you know the answer =)!

Comment: its probably very dependent on what the `something` variable holding during that render statement.  the time of render will be variable based on the content being rendered

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. But since it's a random one every time (while the order of the original `something`-`@collection` keeps the same) I don't really think that's it, right?

Comment: Is this problem in production or development environment?

Comment: Is this in development or production? As cpjolicoeur said, the time it takes to render something does depend on what you are rendering. Also, your caching could be wonky.

Comment: This occurs in both the development and production environment. Caching is turned on only in production (not in development).

Comment: Upgrading my app to Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1 makes rendering those partials 10 times faster =)! There's still one random partial (every single time) that's slower than the others, which is weird, but it isn't really a showstopper anymore.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably **Garbage Collection**.

If you use profiling software (like NewRelic) and a ruby interpreter like Ruby Enterprise Edition (REE) you can turn on GC stats and confirm this and measure how often the GC runs and how much of your time is spent in GC.

As you allocate more objects/data, you will eventually trigger a GC due to size of the data or number of allocations.  This appears almost random and will inject the delay you see.

This appears as "lost time" because you're measuring this within your Ruby VM, which is paused while GC executes.  So you see random spikes like this without activity in the application codebase.

If you're interested in performance tuning or GC behavior, a great place to start is the GC portion of the REE docs:

http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/documentation.html#_garbage_collector_and_object_space

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! What can I do to 'remove the delay'? Is it possible to release variables myself (just like ObjC and stuff) when I finish using them?

Comment: You should start by measuring the activity.  You can switch to an interpreter like REE that will let you tune the GC behavior to be more appropriate for your application (how much you space you initially allocate, how fast it expands, how aggressively it collects, etc).